# Using DOM nextSibling

Tags: javascript, html, dom, userscripts

I'm writing a userscript for a page which has this HTML code block..

```
<span id="mediaSetUfiLikeLink">
    <button class="like_link stat_elem as_link" title="Like this item" type="submit" name="like">
        <span class="default_message">Like</span>
        <span class="saving_message">Unlike</span>
    </button>
</span>

<span>
    <a href="/ajax/sharer/?s=3&appid=2305272732&p[]=1012781954&p[]=2063763" rel="dialog">Share</a>
</span>
```

I need to add an `id` tag to the **last** `span` block. (below one)

```
<span>
    <a href="/ajax/sharer/?s=3&appid=2305272732&p[]=1012781954&p[]=2063763" rel="dialog">Share</a>
</span>
```

I'm got to this point using this,

```
document.getElementById("mediaSetUfiLikeLink").getElementsByTagName("span")[1];
```

I tried getting the last `span` using `nextSibling` like this, which returned `null`

```
document.getElementById("mediaSetUfiLikeLink").getElementsByTagName("span")[1].nextSibling;
```

Can someone please help me out with this? Just to be clear once again, I want to 'gain access' to the last `span` block so that I can add an `id` attribute to it..

**P.S** - I need to do this **without** using jQuery or any other external library. Pure JavaScript only.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("mediaSetUfiLikeLink").nextElementSibling;
```

or

```
function nextElementSibling( elem ) {

    do {

        elem = elem.nextSibling;

    } while( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );

    return elem;
}

var elem = nextElementSibling( document.getElementById("mediaSetUfiLikeLink") );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXGQ6/

Comment: +1 but why bother with the IIFE? It doesn't add any real benefit. http://jsfiddle.net/Ewya7/

Comment: @amnotiam I dunno, I was about to make a general function and then just wrote it like that lol :P

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. :) I like that approach since you can use it like `var next = el.nextElementSibling || nextElementSibling( el )`

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a userscript-capable browser, you can use `document.querySelector`, like so:

```
var node = document.querySelector ("#mediaSetUfiLikeLink + span");

node.id = "myId";
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JddD/).

Comment: +1 Great solution. The *nextAdjacentSibling* selector sure comes in handy sometimes.